# как использовать multitor?

Tags: proxy, tor

Пытаюсь поднять на сервере прокси тора с помощью библиотеки: [multitor](https://github.com/trimstray/multitor)
Поднимал разными способами и с privoxy, просто socks, через HAProxy
Проблема: прокси не подключаются на другом сервере(пробовал тоже по-разному)
как сделать чтобы прокси работали на другом сервере тоже ?